# Tack picture from Android Mobile connect through USB to Windows 7 PC

Tags: android, ms-access, windows-7, camera, usb

I am using [Access Imagine](http://access.bukrek.net/) in MS Access application.
i can nicely Tack Picture from my laptop's integrated camera as per shows in below picture.
[image]

Now i am trying to Capture Image using Android Phone (Motorola Moto E) connected to PC (Windows 7) via USB Cable.

[I just trying to Use Android Phone as USB Web Camera].

Is it Possible?

Then how? please help